# Split file up based on delimiters in php - which is the best to use?

Tags: php, regex, split, explode

I am trying to parse a file using php but I am not sure of the best way to do it. The file consists of stuff like:

```
saturn+5 57 space+shuttle 34 gemini 12 mercury 2 soyuz+tm 1
```

What I'm trying to do is split it up and populate a hash map, so..

```
$inventory["saturn+5"] = "57";
$inventory["space+shuttle"] = "34";
and so on.
```

I don't know how to tackle this.

I am trying to write a bit of regex to process the file to separate out the fields but I'm not having much luck and was wondering if I should try using a different approach using `split()` or `explode()`.

Comment: Well, `explode` would be quite a cumbersome approach. What are you regex attempts?

Comment: My first attempt was something like '/([.*]\s[0-9]*)/' but I don't think this would give me what I wanted. It would give me something like 
$splitstring[0]="saturn+5";
$splitstring[1]="57";$splitstring[2]="space+shuttle";
etc. So I'd have to loop through the array, so the odd numbered indices would be the key and the even indices the value, but this struck me as cumbersome. I thought there was a one-step approach that would do the odd/even index assignation immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach using regular expression.

```
$data = 'saturn+5 57 space+shuttle 34 gemini 12 mercury 2 soyuz+tm 1';

$inventory = array();

preg_match_all('/(\S+) (\S+)/', $data, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $index => $match) {
   $inventory[$match] = $matches[2][$index];
}
print_r($inventory);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [saturn+5] => 57
    [space+shuttle] => 34
    [gemini] => 12
    [mercury] => 2
    [soyuz+tm] => 1
)
```

Comment: There are some great solutions on this page, many thanks. I went for the option above as it was the first one I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

my crude approach:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$str="saturn+5 57 space+shuttle 34 gemini 12 mercury 2 soyuz+tm 1";

//break it on space
$e=explode(' ',$str);

//reindex array to start from 1
array_unshift($e, "phoney");
unset($e[0]);

print_r($e);
$inventory=array();
foreach ($e as $k=>$v){

//detects odd key   
if(($k+2)%2==1) {

$inventory[$v]= $e[$k+1];

    }

}

print_r($inventory);
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PN6K8m

output:

```
Array
(
    [saturn+5] => 57
    [space+shuttle] => 34
    [gemini] => 12
    [mercury] => 2
    [soyuz+tm] => 1
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to reindex the array?

Comment: You can use a negation to avoid this step: `foreach ($e as $k => $v) { if (!($k%2)) $inventory[$v] = $e[$k+1]; }`

Comment: i come from the "get it done" school of programming, im not paid to think

Answer (score 2):

If it's always in that order, this will work:

```
<?

$foo = 'saturn+5 57 space+shuttle 34 gemini 12 mercury 2 soyuz+tm 1';
$foo_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $foo);

$hash = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($foo_array); $i++){
    $i % 2 ? null : $hash[$foo_array[$i]] = $foo_array[++$i];
}

print_r($hash);
?>
```

Output:

```
php foo.php
Array
(
    [saturn+5] => 57
    [space+shuttle] => 34
    [gemini] => 12
    [mercury] => 2
    [soyuz+tm] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works; it seems that there are newline characters in the file, or something odd I hadn't accounted for.
I get this:
Array ( [ saturn+5] => 57 space_shuttle [34 gemini] => 12 mercury [2 soyuz+tm]

Comment: @user3713442: you can use `trim` before.

Comment: `$foo_array = preg_split('/\s+/', $foo);`

Comment: you can improve the loop with:`$length=count($foo_array);for ($i = 0; $i < $length ;$i++){ $hash[$foo_array[$i]] = $foo_array[++$i]; }`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite trivial with a regex:

```
preg_match_all("/  ([\w+]+)  \s  (\d+)  /x", $string, $m);
$assoc = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

You're just looking for a combination of alphanumeric characters `\w` and optional `+` signs, then a space, then a `\d` decimal.

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) will give you the associative array.